# How to get the response object when status >= 300 using http-client call-with-input-request?

Tags: http, error-handling, chicken-scheme

How do I get the response object from `call-with-input-request` when the HTTP status is >= 300?

The [docs](https://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/http-client) say this about `call-with-input-request`:

> Returns three values: The result of the call to reader (or #f if there is no message body in the response), the request-uri of the last request and the response object. If the response code is not in the 200 class, it will raise a condition of type (exn http client-error), (exn http server-error) or (exn http unexpected-server-response), depending on the response code. This includes 404 not found (which is a client-error).

This means that `call-with-input-request` signals a non-continuable condition, which (as far as I understand) means that the function does not return, and I cannot get access to the response object that would otherwise be returned. Therefore I don't see how I can actually get access to the response object corresponding to this request.

I still want to be able to inspect the response, even if its status is in the 30x-50x range. For example, I want to be able to print the HTTP reason string, or log it for debugging later. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trigger the exception from the REPL, you can inspect it with the `,exn` comma-command. Then you'll notice the condition has a `response` property which is a contains the status code, headers etc.

The docs could be improved in this regard I'm sure. Perhaps you have a suggestion where to put this? The problem is that the exact contents of the condition object depend on where the condition was thrown, so not all properties will always be available.

Comment: The problem turned out that I was just using `call-with-input-request` incorrectly anyway (thanks to you all on IRC for the assistance with that). I ended up finding `'response` by browsing the source code. Regarding the docs, I think it would be very helpful to just have a list of the properties that are added to each exception type by default. E.g. "`client-error` has the following properties: (bulleted list here)"